# Where to find jdk 32 bits on macOS?

Tags: java, oracle, macos, api, jmf

I search on the oracle's web but i can't find 32 bits version.
i need to use JMF(Java Multimedia Framework),but don't run correctly with jdk 64 bits. So i can't
find jdk 32 bits for macOS 10.9.4.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get Java JDK 32-Bit running on your macOS is to use [Soylatte](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/static/soylatte/) as it is described here:

[Seapegasus Blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/seapegasus/entry/javafx_and_jdk_6_on)

> If you have one of the 2006 Intel Macs with 32-bit processors, you guessed what I'm talking about: In spring '08, Apple finally released the Apple JDK 6 (or as they call it, "Java for Mac OS 10.5"), but for 64-bit processors only. And there is no sign this will change soon: On Mac hardware, Mac OS X 10.5.2 and an Intel Core 2 processor are the minimum requirements for the JDK 6 -- and also for JavaFX.
>
> Apart from switching to Windows or Linux, or buying new hardware, the only alternative for developers who don't meet those requirements is the Soy Latte JDK 6. Using this JDK solves a few problems but also raises some others. You have to decide whether the pros out-weigh the cons in your work situation:
>
> Pro
>
> - You can use the JavaFX SDK on top of the SoyLatte JDK
> - IDEs like NetBeans work with SoyLatte (you're not stuck on the command line)
> - No need to buy new hardware for JDK 6 / JavaFX development
>
> Con
>
> - Must use X11 whose user-interface needs getting used too (shortcuts, menus).
> - Installation is less straight-forward than installing the Apple JDK
> - No support for Java Web Start (javaws) yet